# How can I programmatically hide VS Code's outline view in the Explorer View?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

how to hide outline view in sidebar forever. I want to hide outline view forever by code.
I try to execute `vscode.commands.executeCommand('outline.removeView')`
it can work when the extension actived first time, but not work when actived the second.
That is to say execute twice about the command `vscode.commands.executeCommand('outline.removeView')`,the outline view will show again.Is this a bug of vscode

I try to execute `vscode.commands.executeCommand('outline.removeView')`
it can work when the extension actived first time, but not work when actived the second.
That is to say execute twice about the command `vscode.commands.executeCommand('outline.removeView')`,the outline view will show again